# Oracle - Recursive query using START WITH... CONNECTED BY...?

Tags: sql, oracle10g, recursive-query

Say i have the following table, using Oracle 10g

```
 ARTIFACT_LABEL |   DEPENDANT_ON
 test1          |   abc1
 test1          |   abc2
 test1          |   abc3
 abc3           |   xyz1
 abc4           |   xyz2
```

and i want to generate a tree structure knowing what `test1` depends on, (so i want to return, `abc1, abc2, abc3, xyz1`) ive been using the following:

`SELECT ARTIFACT_LABEL, DEPENDANT_ON
FROM DEPENDANCIES
START WITH ARTIFACT_LABEL = 'test1'
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR ARTIFACT_LABEL = DEPENDANT_ON`

But this isnt working (it seems to just be doing a `SELECT where ARTIFACT_LABEL = 'test1'`)

Any ideas where im going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are starting at the bottom of the tree and working up, change the last part of the query to:

```
PRIOR DEPENDANT_ON = ARTIFACT_LABEL
```

Comment: Just found this out a few minutes after posting the question - should stop being lazy and do all the testing myself before asking others. Thanks for the help