# Order by parent

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a STUDENT table:

- ID NUMBER(8)
- PARENT_ID NUMBER(8)

with data:

```
54, 99
50, null
5, 54,
99, 50
```

How can I query them in this order?

```
50 <-- first, because it has no parent, so it's root
99 <-- second, because it's parent is the root item
54 <-- third, because it's parent is the second item
5  <-- forth, because it's parent is the third item
```

Comment: Could you post what you've tried so far? A hint: in Oracle you can do this with a [hierarchical query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries003.htm).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle - Recursive query using START WITH... CONNECTED BY...?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7149962/oracle-recursive-query-using-start-with-connected-by)

Comment: @EdGibbs, thank you! I didn't know hierarchical query up until now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a `CONNECT BY` clause.

See the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd2fc/4).

Comment: +1 - nice! Just so you know, you can get the same result using `START WITH Parent_ID IS NULL` and avoid the subquery. The fiddle is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cd2fc/5).

Comment: You're absolutely right, Ed.  I overcomplicated it a bit, didn't I?